# Does Jabari tribe also have Vibranium mines and tech?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, black-panther-2018

Jabari tribe didn't live with the other tribes and they used to worship Hanuman instead of Bast. Jabari also had a gorilla monument instead of panther.

The big mine we saw in the movie had an entrance through a panther's mouth. So, it definitely didn't look like a collaboration between all tribes.

Although, technically, Jabari could claim its ownership by winning the rulership of Wakanda, did they have their own Vibranium mines and tech in separated state?

Comment: Since they were living in the caves, I'd say probably not.

Comment: The question then becomes: did they live in caves because they had no access, or because they chose that life?

Comment: @Irishpanda - Mainly the latter. They were traditionalists. They rejected modern technology, I believe. Of course, the Panther tribe and others probably didn’t go out of their way to accommodate them - from the sound of it, the Wakandan government kind of ignored them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Jabari are specifically against the use of Vibranium and the modern tech that it enables. They are traditionalists, and eschew the modernity that comes from using the metal.

According to an interview with Winston Duke (M'Baku from the movie), the Jabari rely on a special kind of wood, that when treated can stand toe to toe with Vibranium:

[Article about the interview](https://www.inverse.com/article/41498-black-panther-vibranium-jabari-mbaku)

Comment: A special kind of wood, mmm…mutated from vibranium exposure like the heart-shaped herb, no doubt? ;)

Comment: That would actually make sense.